# Creating a more concise traversal of a stack for DFS algorithm - Java

Tags: java, graph, stack, traversal, depth-first-search

I am trying to get this code running as fast as possible when traversing through my stack of my DFS currently the input files are like so:

```
0 2
2 1
1 4
4 5
5 6
10 8
8 9
9 6
7 6
3 4
0 1
3 9
0 4
```

Where my Maze class will tie the numbers together and create a graph for me. After the graph is created my DFS class runs through traversing giving one or all solutions to the .txt file submitted. My DFS class looks like so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class DFS {
    //starting node, the route to the next node, has node been visited
    private int startNode; 
    private int[] route2;
    private boolean[] visited;


    // 2 main arguments - Maze File & user input
    public DFS(Maze maze, int inputInt) {
        int startNode = 0;
        int goal = 1;
        route2 = new int[maze.node];
        visited = new boolean[maze.node];
        if(inputInt == 1){
        startDFSone(maze, startNode, goal);
        }
        else if (inputInt == 2){
        startDFSall(maze, startNode, goal);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("input invalid. No Solution Returned");
        }
    }


    //Put path to goal in the stack
    public Stack<Integer> route2(int toGoalNode) {
        if (!visited[toGoalNode]) {
            return null;
        }
        Stack<Integer> pathStack = new Stack<Integer>();
        for (int route2GoalNode = toGoalNode; route2GoalNode != startNode; route2GoalNode = route2[route2GoalNode]) {
            pathStack.push(route2GoalNode);
        }
        pathStack.push(startNode);
        reverseStack(pathStack);
        return pathStack;
    }

    //Reverse the stack
    public void reverseStack(Stack<Integer> stackToBeReverse) {

        if (stackToBeReverse.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        int bottom = popBottomStack(stackToBeReverse);
        reverseStack(stackToBeReverse);
        stackToBeReverse.push(bottom);
    }

    //Pop the bottom of the stack
    private int popBottomStack(Stack<Integer> stackToBeReverse) {
        int popTopStack = stackToBeReverse.pop();
        if (stackToBeReverse.isEmpty()) {
            return popTopStack;
        } else {
            int bottomStack = popBottomStack(stackToBeReverse);
            stackToBeReverse.push(popTopStack);
            return bottomStack;
        }
    }

    //performs DFS and unsets visited to give the result of all paths 
    private void startDFSall(Maze maze, int node, int goal) {
        visited[node] = true; 
        if(node == goal) { 
            printPath(goal);
        } else {
            for (int con : maze.getadjList(node)) {
                if (!visited[con]) {
                    route2[con] = node;
                    startDFSall(maze, con, goal);
                }
            }
        }
        visited[node] = false; 
    }

  //performs DFS and maintains visited marker giving only one path
    private void startDFSone(Maze maze, int node, int goal) {
            visited[node] = true;
            for (int con : maze.getadjList(node)) {
                if (!visited[con]) {
                    route2[con] = node;
                    startDFSone(maze, con, goal);
                }
            }
        }

    //Traverse the connections to the goal and print the path taken
    public void printPath( int toGoal) {
        int goalNode = 1;
        if (visited[toGoal]) {
            System.out.println("Completed Path: ");
            for (int t : route2(toGoal)) {
                if (t == toGoal) {
                    System.out.print(t);
                } else {
                    System.out.print(t + " -> ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(System.in);
        int goalNode = 1;
        System.out.print("Enter maze file: ");
        String file = scanFile.nextLine();
        Maze maze = new Maze(file);
        Scanner scanInt = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter desired feedback (1 = one soultion, 2 = all): ");
        int inputInt = scanInt.nextInt();
        maze.print();
        System.out.println();           
        DFS dfs = new DFS(maze, inputInt);
        dfs.printPath(goalNode);
        }

}
```

I am asking for some example or pointers to get my code (specifically the traversal of the stack) more concise so that when I implement my testing for completion time of the code I can minimize it as much as humanly possible.

I'll link my Maze class below if it might help. Thanks.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Maze {

final static Set<Integer> Nodes = new HashSet<Integer>();
List<Integer>[] adjList;
int node; //declaring value for my nodes.
int con; // declaring a connection

/**
 * This constructors takes an integer parameter for reading node indexes in
 * a list of adjacent nodes.
 *
 * @param node - integer parameter for passing the nodes value from the file
 * and create a list of adjacent nodes.
 */
Maze(int node) {
    this.node = node;
    this.con = 0;
    adjList = (List<Integer>[]) new List[node];
    for (int index = 0; index < node; index++) {
        adjList[index] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }
}

/**
 * The main constructor that takes a String for reading maze file.
 *
 * @param mazeFile
 */
public Maze(String mazeFile) {
    this(getNodeSize(mazeFile));
    Scanner scan;
    try {
        //Creates a scanner for reading the file and loops through linking the nodes to their connections.
        scan = new Scanner(new File(mazeFile));

        while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            int node1 = scan.nextInt();
            int node2 = scan.nextInt();
            addCon(node1, node2);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found.");
    }
}

/**
 * This method returns a size of the set of nodes by taking a String
 * parameter which the name of the maze file.
 *
 * @param mazeFile - String parameter for reading maze file for scanning the
 * size of the nodes.
 * @return - returns an integer value for the size of the set of nodes.
 */
public static int getNodeSize(String mazeFile) {
    Scanner scanNodeSize;
    try {
        scanNodeSize = new Scanner(new File(mazeFile));
        while (scanNodeSize.hasNextInt()) {
            int node1 = scanNodeSize.nextInt();
            int node2 = scanNodeSize.nextInt();
            Nodes.add(node1);
            Nodes.add(node2);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Nodes.size();
}

/**
 * This method adds an con by adding two different nodes in array of list
 * called adjacency list.
 *
 * @param node1 - first node.
 * @param node2 - next node.
 */
private void addCon(int node1, int node2) {
    con++; //Increase con by one whenever this addcon method is called.
    adjList[node1].add(node2);
    adjList[node2].add(node1);
}

/**
 * Print the nodes and its cons by looping through the adjacency list.
 */
public void print() {

    for (int n = 0; n < node; n++) {
        System.out.print(n + " connected to ");
        for (int w : adjList[n]) {
            System.out.print(w + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

/**
 * This method returns a list of nodes to allow objects to be the target for
 * "for-each" statement.
 *
 * @param nodes - an Integer parameter for getting the number of nodes in a
 * list.
 * @return - returns a list of nodes.
 */
public Iterable<Integer> getadjList(int nodes) {
    return adjList[nodes];
}

/**
 * Unit testing To test if it reads the file.
 *
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter File: ");
    Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(System.in);
    String file = scanFile.nextLine();
    Maze M = new Maze(file);
    M.print();
    }

}
```

Also any general input would be fantastic.

Comment: This question format is not well-suited for StackOverflow. It is too broad and mostly opinion-based. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349513/are-code-improvement-questions-allowed. It would be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.